# Jquery Date picker all dates appearing as unselectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have implemented the jquery date picker on my website and all dates seem to appear as unselectable.

Below is the code that is outputted

`<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>`

Please help

Comment: You have implemented codes to restrict date to be selected by user? If yes pls share it.

Comment: please show the code in which you initiate the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "ui-datepicker-unselectable". Also "ui-state-disabled" if that is not enough.

Comment: This `ui-datepicker-unselectable` is automatically appearing in the date picker

Comment: How do you initialize the datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the strings of "ui-datepicker-unselectable" and "ui-state-disabled" in your project. Among the results you should find the exact place where these unneeded classes are added. Modify your code to not add these classes. If that is not enough, debug Javascript and find the exact places in the code where the classes are added.